# Disable 3rdparty hook from custom module once

Tags: 7, hooks

Im using the `menu_trail_by_path` which does a pretty good job for most of my URL's, however in a custom module I'm setting the breadcrumbs directly (`drupal_set_breadcrumb` in a page callback). These crumbs get messed up due the `menu_trail_by_path` module (sort of overwritten I guess =/)

This happens because `menu_trail_by_path` sets the crumbs using `hook_page_delivery_callback_alter` which is called after the page callback apparently.

I would like to keep my custom crumbs in the page callback as it has all the required (dynamic) data available.

Hero we go.. how on earth can I disable the `page_delivery_callback_alter` hook from the `menu_trail_by_path` module... once? I.e. for the current runtime /request only.

Thanks!

Roland Franssen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) to avoid a hook implemented by a module is invoked. The problem is that Drupal saves in cache the list of modules implementing a hook, but you can change the list of hooks implemented by modules back to the original one.

```
function mymodule_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($your_condition && ($hook == 'page_delivery_callback_alter')) {
    $old_implementations = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
    if (empty($old_implementations)) {
      $old_implementations = array_merge(array(), $implementations);
      unset($implementations['menu_trail_by_path']);
    }
  }
}

function mymodule_exit() {
  $old_implementations = &drupal_static('mymodule_implements_alter', array());
  $implementations = &drupal_static('module_implements');

  if (!empty($old_implementations)) {
    $implementations['page_deliver_callback_alter'] = $old_implementations;
  }
}
```

This code works only in the case `hook_exit()` is invoked, which is normally done in [`drupal_page_footer()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_page_footer/7).

You should be sure `mymodule_implements_alter()` is executed after the implementations made from other modules, in order to preserve the changes done from other modules.

Comment: Oh dear god :-)

Comment: This is inception!